# In the orthogonal series, when finding the 4-force between two charges would the entire world line of each need to be taken into account?

Tags: physics, alternate-reality, electromagnetism

[Four-Velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) is the derivative of [four-position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector#Four-position) with respect to [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time), four-acceleration is the derivative of four-velocity with respect to proper time, and four-force is equal to [rest mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Rest_mass) multiplied by four-acceleration.

In the universe described in the [Orthogonal Series](https://www.gregegan.net/ORTHOGONAL/ORTHOGONAL.html) if there are two electric charges A and B, then there could be a point C on As worldline, for which point D on Bs worldline is in As present at C, but point C on As worldline is not in Bs present at D.  This would mean that point D on Bs worldline would need to be taken into account when calculating the electric four-force on A at point C, and in the universe described in the orthogonal series [Conservation of energy](https://www.gregegan.net/ORTHOGONAL/02/Motion.html#CL) and momentum would apply.  So this would mean that point C on As worldline would also need to be taken into account when finding the electric force on B at point D, implying that a point on As worldline does not need to be in Bs present at D in order to exert a four-force on D.

My question is, if there were two or more electric charges interacting with each other, in the universe described in the orthogonal series, would it be necessary to take every point along the world line of each electric charge into consideration, when finding the four-force acting on a particular electric charge along its worldline?

Comment: For referrence see this meta-discussion on questions relating to [third-party or commercial worlds](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/policy-clarification-asking-about-commercial-or-third-party-worlds).

Comment: Sounds a bit complex for WB SE (but I've been wrong before :-) ).  I'd suggest reading this [answer on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/87085/104964) and particularly the comment about the [Liénard–Wiechert potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential).  That is to say maybe using the retarded potentials instead of trying to deal with forces.  My limited understanding is that using forces is the reason you have this issue with every point on a world line and using retarded potentials instead is the solution to that.

Comment: What is worldline?

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Worldlines are from general relativity, they  are paths through space-time, ie lines of 4D points that satisfy [$t(\lambda),x(\lambda),y(\lambda),z(\lambda),$], where $\lambda$ is just a parameter along the line, and $t,x,y,z$ are functions of $\lambda$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because more than a year previous to this question it was [established in Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7336/40609) that questions about third-party or commercial worlds are off-topic. This question should have been asked at [scifi.se].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I see it more appropriate to Physics SE